# Can the last await be replaced with an explicit wait?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.5, async-await

I'm still learning the `async`/`await`, so please excuse me if I'm asking something obvious. Consider the following example:

```
class Program  {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var result = FooAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    static async Task<int> FooAsync() {

        var t1 = Method1Async();
        var t2 = Method2Async();

        var result1 = await t1;
        var result2 = await t2;

        return result1 + result2;

    }

    static Task<int> Method1Async() {
        return Task.Run(
            () => {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                return 11;
            }
        );
    }

    static Task<int> Method2Async() {
        return Task.Run(
            () => {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                return 22;
            }
        );
    }

}
```

This behaves as expected and prints "33" in the console.

If I replace the **second** `await` with an explicit wait...

```
static async Task<int> FooAsync() {

    var t1 = Method1Async();
    var t2 = Method2Async();

    var result1 = await t1;
    var result2 = t2.Result;

    return result1 + result2;

}
```

...I seem to get the same behavior.

Are these two examples completely equivalent?

And if they are equivalent in this case, are there any other cases where replacing the last `await` by an explicit wait would make a difference?

Comment: Just run the same code in a winform app to see why they're not equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I figured this out so let me sum it up, in what will hopefully be a more complete  explanation than the answers provided so far...

### Short Answer

Replacing the second `await` with an explicit wait will have no appreciable effect on a console application, but will block the UI thread of a WPF or WinForms application for the duration of the wait.

Also, the exception handling is slightly different (as noted by Stephen Cleary).

### Long Answer

In a nutshell, the `await` does this:

1. If the awaited task has already finished, it just retrieves its result and continues.
2. If it hasn't, it [posts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx) the continuation (the rest of the method after the `await`) to the [current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx) synchronization context, if there is one. Essentially, `await` is trying to return us where we started from.

   - If there isn't a current context, it just uses the original [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx), which is usually thread pool.

The second (and third and so on...) `await` does the same.

Since the console applications typically have no synchronization context, continuations will typically be handled by the thread pool, so there is no issue if we block within the continuation.

WinForms or WPF, on the other hand, have synchronization context implemented on top of their message loop. Therefore, `await` executed on a UI thread will (eventually) execute its continuation on the UI thread as well. If we happen to block in the continuation, it will block the message loop and make the UI non-responsive until we unblock. OTOH, if we just `await`, it will neatly post continuations to be eventually executed on the UI thread, without ever blocking the UI thread.

In the following WinForms form, containing one button and one label, using `await` keeps the UI responsive at all times (note the `async` in front of the click handler):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var result = await FooAsync();
        label1.Text = result.ToString();
    }

    static async Task<int> FooAsync() {

        var t1 = Method1Async();
        var t2 = Method2Async();

        var result1 = await t1;
        var result2 = await t2;

        return result1 + result2;

    }

    static Task<int> Method1Async() {
        return Task.Run(
            () => {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                return 11;
            }
        );
    }

    static Task<int> Method2Async() {
        return Task.Run(
            () => {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                return 22;
            }
        );
    }

}
```

If we replaced the second `await` in `FooAsync` with `t2.Result`, it would continue to be responsive for about 3 seconds after the button click, and then freeze for about 2 seconds:

- The continuation after the first `await` will politely wait its turn to be scheduled on the UI thread, which would happen after `Method1Async()` task finishes, i.e. after about 3 seconds,
- at which point the `t2.Result` will rudely block the UI thread until the `Method2Async()` task finishes, about 2 seconds later.

If we removed the `async` in front of the `button1_Click` and replaced its `await` with `FooAsync().Result` it would deadlock:

- The UI thread would wait on `FooAsync()` task to finish,
- which would wait on its continuation to finish,
- which would wait on the UI thread to become available,
- which it isn't, since it is blocked by the `FooAsync().Result`.

The article ["Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx) by Stephen Toub was invaluable to me in understanding this subject.

Answer (score 2):

Your replacement version blocks the calling thread waiting for the task to finish. It's hard to see a visible difference in a console app like that since you're intentionally blocking in Main, but they're definitely not equivalent.

Comment: My calling thread is blocked in both cases by calling `Result` on `FooAsync()`. But without that, it would not block in either case, so what's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

They are not equivalent.

`Task.Result` blocks until the result is available. As I explain on my blog, this [can cause deadlocks](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) if you have an `async` context that requires exclusive access (e.g., a UI or ASP.NET app).

Also, `Task.Result` will wrap any exceptions in `AggregateException`, so error handling is harder if you synchronously block.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the deadlock can occur because of the message-loop interactions, not simply because we are waiting on a task that happens to have a "interdependent" wait in its continuation. I obviously don't have a message loop here, so that shouldn't be a problem, correct?

Comment: As for exception handling, I'd expect the explicit wait to have one more level of `AggregateException` (inside the `AggregateException` of the "outer" task), but otherwise should be fairly similar - no exceptions will be lost in either case, correct?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: Any kind of `async` context that has exclusive access (including but not limited to "message loop" systems) will cause a deadlock. If you're actually developing an `async` Console program, then you don't have a context like that.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: `await` will unwrap `AggregateException`s automatically, so in pure `async` code you never have to deal with the `AggregateException` type.